# Typescript - Create an exhaustive Tuple type from another type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a pseudo-interface in typescript. The desired behavior would look something like this:

I'd like to create a type containing any number of action groups which contain any number of actions

```
type MyActionInterface = { 
    ActionGroup1: { 
        Action1: () => number, 
        Action2: (x:number) => string 
    },
    ActionGroup2: {
        Action1: (x: number, y:number) => void, 
        Action2: (x:string) => number
    }
}
```

Which can then be used to describe my concrete implementation object

```
const someInterfacedObject:ActionInterface<MyActionInterface> = {
    ActionGroup1: [
        {
            name: 'Action1',
            call: () => 3
        },
        {
            name: 'Action2',
            call: (x) => "X"+x
        }
    ],
    ActionGroup2: [
        {
            name: 'Action1',
            call: (x, y) => { }
        },
        {
            name: 'Action2',
            call: (x) => 3
        }
    ]
}
```

The code currently looks like this and works somewhat

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type AnyFunction = (...args:any) => any

type Action<N, F> = {
    name: N
    call: F
}   

type ActionInterface<Definition> = 
{ 
    [groupname in keyof Definition] : Action<keyof Definition[groupname], ValueOf<Definition[groupname]>>[]
}
```

Now the type of, for example, `ActionGroup1` in `someInterfacedObject` resolves as

```
ActionGroup1: Action<"Action1" | "Action2", (() => number) | ((x: number) => string)>[]
```

which does still allow me to omit actions or input undesired combinations of name/function

I'd like to get typescript to resolve `ActionGroup1` as

```
[Action<"Action1", () => number>, Action<"Action2", (x:number) => string>]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to require that the `name` and the `call` properties match up (so you can't use "undesired combinations of name/function"), you can do it like this:

```
type ActionInterfaceArray<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Array<
    { [P in keyof T[K]]: { name: P; call: T[K][P] } }[keyof T[K]]
  >
};
```

Basically you're iterating over all the subproperties `P` of each property `K` of `T` and then unioning together the `{name: P; call: T[K][P]}`.  So you end up with `Array<{name: "Action1", call: ()=>number} | {name: "Action2", call: (x: number)=>string}>`.

For `ActionInterfaceArray<MyActionInterface>`, you get

```
{
    ActionGroup1: ({
        name: "Action1";
        call: () => number;
    } | {
        name: "Action2";
        call: (x: number) => string;
    })[];
    ActionGroup2: ({
        name: "Action1";
        call: (x: number, y: number) => void;
    } | {
        name: "Action2";
        call: (x: string) => number;
    })[];
}
```

This is the simplest approach, by far.

---

Unfortunately it doesn't solve the "allow me to omit actions" problem.  You can't really output a tuple type like `[{name: "Action1", call: ()=>number}, {name: "Action2", call: (x: number)=>string}]`, since the original `ActionGroup1` is an object type, and object types don't have ordered keys.  So nothing in the language will say "place `Action1` first and `Action2` second", and that's not even what you're trying to do, is it?

You could *potentially* represent a union of all possible tuple types, such as `[{name: "Action1", call: ()=>number}, {name: "Action2", call: (x: number)=>string}] | [{name: "Action2", call: (x: number)=>string}, {name: "Action1", call: ()=>number}]`, but this is both a real pain to generate programmatically and results in an unmanageable combinatorial explosion of tuples for even a modest number of terms.  (e.g., turning `Array<A | B | C | D>` into `[A, B, C, D] | [A, B, D, C] | [A, C, B, D] | [A, C, D, B] | [A, D, B, C] | [A, D, C, B] | [B, A, C, D] | [B, A, D, C] | [B, C, A, D] | [B, C, D, A] | [B, D, A, C] | [B, D, C, A] | [C, A, B, D] | [C, A, D, B] | [C, B, A, D] | [C, B, D, A] | [C, D, A, B] | [C, D, B, A] | [D, A, B, C] | [D, A, C, B] | [D, B, A, C] | [D, B, C, A] | [D, C, A, B] | [D, C, B, A]`)   I wouldn't recommend this, but here's one way to get close (The natural implementation of `UnionToAllPossibleTuples<T>` is recursive in a way the TypeScript compiler doesn't like, so I've unrolled it into something that will deal with unions of up to seven members):

```
type UnionToAllPossibleTuples<T> = UTAPT<T>;
type UTAPT<T, U = T> = [T] extends [never] ? [] : T extends any ? Cons<T, UTAPT1<Exclude<U, T>>> : never;
type UTAPT1<T, U = T> = [T] extends [never] ? [] : T extends any ? Cons<T, UTAPT2<Exclude<U, T>>> : never;
type UTAPT2<T, U = T> = [T] extends [never] ? [] : T extends any ? Cons<T, UTAPT3<Exclude<U, T>>> : never;
type UTAPT3<T, U = T> = [T] extends [never] ? [] : T extends any ? Cons<T, UTAPT4<Exclude<U, T>>> : never;
type UTAPT4<T, U = T> = [T] extends [never] ? [] : T extends any ? Cons<T, UTAPT5<Exclude<U, T>>> : never;
type UTAPT5<T, U = T> = [T] extends [never] ? [] : T extends any ? Cons<T, UTAPT6<Exclude<U, T>>> : never;
type UTAPT6<T, U = T> = [T] extends [never] ? [] : T extends any ? Cons<T, UTAPT7<Exclude<U, T>>> : never;
type UTAPT7<T, U = T> = [];

type Cons<T, U = []> = U extends any[]
  ? ((t: T, ...u: U) => void) extends ((...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never
  : [T];
```

and then

```
type ActionInterfaceTuples<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: UnionToAllPossibleTuples<
    { [P in keyof T[K]]: { name: P; call: T[K][P] } }[keyof T[K]]
  >
};
```

For `ActionInterfaceTuples<MyActionInterface>`, you get:

```
{
    ActionGroup1: [{
        name: "Action1";
        call: () => number;
    }, {
        name: "Action2";
        call: (x: number) => string;
    }] | [{
        name: "Action2";
        call: (x: number) => string;
    }, {
        name: "Action1";
        call: () => number;
    }];
    ActionGroup2: [{
       name: "Action1";
        call: (x: number, y: number) => void;
    }, {
        name: "Action2";
        call: (x: string) => number;
    }] | [{
        name: "Action2";
        call: (x: string) => number;
    }, {
        name: "Action1";
        call: (x: number, y: number) => void;
    }];
}
```

which works well enough here, but... yuck.

---

Another thing you could do is make a generic type `ActionInterfaceGeneric<T, U>` that tries to verify that a candidate type `U` has all the required properties corresponding to the subproperties of `T`.  It's based on `ActionInterfaceArray<T>`, but if any of the passed in arrays are missing keys (`keyof T[K] extends U[K][number]["name"]` is false), then you will make the type require the missing key.  The errors aren't great, and it's hard to read, but here it is:

```
type ActionInterfaceGeneric<T, U extends ActionInterfaceArray<T>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: keyof T[K] extends U[K][number]["name"]
    ? U[K]
    : [{ name: Exclude<keyof T[K], U[K][number]["name"]>; call: any }]
};

const asActionInterface = <T>() => <
  U extends ActionInterfaceArray<T> & ActionInterfaceGeneric<T, U>
>(
  u: U
) => u;
```

That will work for your correct value:

```
const someInterfacedObject = asActionInterface<MyActionInterface>()({
  ActionGroup1: [
    {
      name: "Action1",
      call: () => 3
    },
    {
      name: "Action2",
      call: x => "X" + x
    }
  ],
  ActionGroup2: [
    {
      name: "Action1",
      call: (x, y) => {}
    },
    {
      name: "Action2",
      call: () => 3
    }
  ]
});
```

but for an incorrect value you'll get some errors:

```
const badInterfacedObject = asActionInterface<MyActionInterface>()({
  ActionGroup1: [
    {
      name: "Action1",
      call: () => 3
    },
    {
      name: "Action2",
      call: x => "X" + x
    }
  ],
  ActionGroup2: [    
    {
      name: "Action2",  // error! '"Action2"' is not assignable to type '"Action1"'.
      call: () => 3
    }
  ]
});
```

That error, `"Action2" is not assignable to "Action1"` is a bit confusing, especially since if you change it to `"Action1"` it will switch the error to `"Action2"`.  Really you want the error to say something like "hey your array isn't long enough", but it's hard to get [custom error messages](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689).  The above is close enough to demonstrate the general approach.

---

So, both `ActionInterfaceGeneric` and `ActionInterfaceTuples` are complicated in their own ways, and `ActionInterfaceArray` is incomplete... these problems indicate that TypeScript's type system isn't really quite geared for this sort of thing.  If you wanted to play nicely with TypeScript, I'd suggest ditching arrays-which-need-to-exactly-match-objects and just use the objects themselves.  This might not be feasible for you, of course.  If so, I'd probably just go with `ActionInterfaceArray` and use some prominent documentation that care must be taken when using it. But it's up to you which (if any) of these to use.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYElXAgJwGYCGcEMOOBIAPACoB8UAvFAN4CwAUFFANoDSUiVFADWEEMjxRqAXQBcsMhUocuXZjwAKAoaPGTqfaXJZRUBALYR5GgNxQ4BADaP5B3tO4bpUAL6-uuhJShtIqULQcPjYcHAD0AFSJScnJsTHsoJBQAMJoAM40ADRQAKqMPNL0TGUQAB7YqAAmeVAEqCDcoZxQAPxQABT9wK7FAHTjAK7yJQCUjPQAbsiIjXN1Dc0D-eOjOPKCeLhQAEpzDIvLq70nUPKoEAu4YfLcMtHsHJnQJagoqNTIGDODTIPJ5RAAI0cEGoEzA0IKdHKJWoMA01BotHeX1KqPRRVK5SRTFe3nWECaLW490eOC6XD6nWeUig5MprXa11yqERxRRaOoAEZKABRWpwRwTRoQSglYp0Wj0O4PXDY8DfPFCgllJjEngyVn1CmbakqulhRn024stmbNogLn5bWagBMovFkulsvliqVpjNaqy-PRbuofKJVX1ZKN7NNtKtluZ1ENGxa9sdPOdAoAzO6JVKZXKpL7rTTVZ91bic9qI+VSSnjVSy+buonuq4G+z031ubyq+iACx5z2Fn2K0sBitBzVDsOE3WR+u2ptmhMVJOdu2cntOufB6gAVmHBe9xfHytpgY1AqPe9rJINy54zbXTPbNpjW4dO8ze81ADZjy9IsFT9Zsr37ahALvBc60fT8V3jC113fZMn27HJdz5TUAHYgNHM8wMnDJK33PCYOLOtpHeKdoHgJA0EwbB8CIGE4QRTFyjYbo+G0EQxCCGRpl+NAASBRwQTBSFoVheEIAKMI1E0PjAn0EJ5HUMxLGsOwHGcVxDE8bw-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-fZwVU4T9Ow9qPnvuYHxo9j72vdUevG+ul0W+9kORvx76o7jnvukmmY-tVsmoAhAhGkt4g9cN425qYM3bduq2bYtu3iAdp3y-Zt2wBRmu44HxPfYbgO+-H0Op4jmfvZj2vW6HlOb9vYf0ztnPOhdi6z1Lm-CuTNq5-3Hj7bSL92aj2KLEWIrIyDIBwAAQigAAcmHn8UeBCBAtFQMgOaZtwSUzMFCaAwBkBQBxEQgOBDRhpxAeHc4kcS7z0iIvDgQA)