# Array containing all options of type value in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Here is code forcing all options of type to present in keys of **object** (and not allowing other keys):

```
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'peach';
const objectWithAllFruitsAsKeys: {
  [ key in Fruit ]: any
} = { apple: '', peach: '' }
```

I am looking for typing formula, allowing close behaviour with values of array — to get **array** with all Fruit type's values presenting in it as values.

```
const arrayWithAllFruitsAsvalues: ??? = ['apple', 'peach'];
```

Do you guys have any ideas?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Depending on your use case, `Array<Fruit>` will work, or you could go down the path of [forcing the type system to guarantee that your array is exhaustive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58170994/2887218) but it's a mess.  Does `Fruit` already exist as a type?  Or can you define it from your array as [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58504957/2887218) suggests?

Answer (score 41):

If you define the array first, here's a way to get the `Fruit` type

```
const arrayWithAllFruitsAsvalues = ['apple', 'peach'] as const;

type Fruit = typeof arrayWithAllFruitsAsvalues[number];  // "apple" | "peach"

const objectWithAllFruitsAsKeys: {
  [ key in Fruit ]: any
} = { apple: '', peach: '' }
```

Comment: This solution is so clever. I love it!

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that this exists. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The type system isn't particularly geared toward guaranteeing that a given tuple has exactly the same values and number of elements as the member of a given union type.  There are all kinds of ways to try to get this to happen.

I'll present one way: make an helper function that takes a union type (like `Fruit`) and returns an array *builder* that prompts the developer to add each individual member of the union, and at each step it removes the previously added members from the list of possible next elements, and finally only lets you build the array.  This only really works for a union of [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) (or other unit types which have only one possible value each).

Here it is (and you could shove it in a library somewhere if it's too ugly to look at)

```
// TS4.0+
type Push<T extends readonly any[], V> = [...T, V];
type ReadonlyTuple<T> = Extract<Readonly<T>, readonly any[]>;

interface TupleBuilderAddable<U, T extends readonly any[]> {
    add<V extends U>(v: V): [U] extends [V] ?
        TupleBuilderBuildable<ReadonlyTuple<Push<T, V>>> :
        TupleBuilderAddable<Exclude<U, V>, ReadonlyTuple<Push<T, V>>>;
}
interface TupleBuilderBuildable<T extends readonly any[]> {
    build(): T;
}
function tupleBuilder<U>():
    [U] extends [never] ?
    TupleBuilderBuildable<[]> :
    TupleBuilderAddable<U, []> {
    const tuple: any[] = [];
    const ret = {
        add(v: any) {
            tuple.push(v);
            return ret;
        },
        build() {
            return tuple;
        }
    }
    return ret as any;
}
```

"Brief" explanation:

- `Push<T, V>` takes a tuple type `T` and some type `V` and makes a new tuple with `V` appended to the end of `T`.
- `TupleBuilderBuildable<T>` takes a tuple type `T` and represents an object with a `build()` method that returns a value of type `T`.
- `TupleBuilderAddable<U, T>` takes a union type `U` and a tuple type `T` and represents an object with an `add()` method.  This `add()` method accepts a value of type `V` that extends `U`.  Conceptually it will remove `V` from `U` to get a new union type `U'`, and then push `V` onto the `T` tuple to get a new tuple type `T'`.  If `U'` is empty, `add()` returns `TupleBuilderBuildable<T'>`. Otherwise it returns `TupleBuilderAddable<U', T'>`.  This is the important step in the type system: every time you call `add()`, it shifts one element from the union to the tuple.

At runtime, you just have a function that returns an object with both an `add()` and a `build()` method that pushes onto an array and returns an array, respectively.  But at compile time only `add()` or `build()` is exposed depending on whether there's anything left in the union type that you haven't used.

---

Enough explanation; here's how you'd use it:

```
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'peach';

const t = tupleBuilder<Fruit>().add("apple").add("peach").build();
// const t: readonly ["apple", "peach"]
```

IntelliSense will only allow you to do certain things:

```
const builder0 = tupleBuilder<Fruit>();
// const builder0: TupleBuilderAddable<Fruit, []>
// builder0 only has an add() method
builder0.add("cherry"); // error! "cherry" is not assignable to Fruit.
const builder1 = builder0.add("peach"); // okay
// const builder1: TupleBuilderAddable<"apple", readonly ["peach"]>
// builder1 only has an add method
builder1.add("peach"); // error! "peach" is not assignable to "apple".
const builder2 = builder1.add("apple"); // okay
// const builder2: TupleBuilderBuildable<readonly ["peach", "apple"]>
// builder2 only has a build method
const u = builder2.build();
// const u: readonly ["peach", "apple"]
```

It forces you to `add()` `"apple"` and `"cherry"` in some order and then `build()`.  Yes, it's verbose, but the compiler gives you hints the whole way through.  You can't call `build()` before you've added all the elements, and you can't call `add()` when you have, and you can't add incorrect or repeated elements.  And when you're all done you have a tuple type.

---

Not sure if this matches your use case, but I just wanted to show one possibility. Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-pr-39094-7#code/C4TwDgpgBACgrgZwBYB4AqUIA9gQHYAmCUAThAIYED2eANiFOXiANoC6ANFAGoB8UAXigsAdGLRdubANwBYAFALQkKACUK1OiDRwwtCOn5CAojhLkAxsBTrKNeoa5k7Wxs3a85i+QEs8uEgAzS2gdPQgAITgfWgIIEgBBAgJyACN9FABVLgxsXEJiZ016N1Y2fgBvBSgaxmSUbkwcfCIoTN4ACgA3AC4eAEo+lky2JvzWlikoAH5q2vmw-SiYuJJl2LSM22LtXQz4ZHRJXhOoHrn5msXI6Nj4pJT0g1MLWjg4rOOubftd8JQDqgJDwTp4FABfBR+ALBCyhPY3FbxdaPDK5ZoFUgaX6lDxQKryeapW4EDqDKBoLyQ+SBOB4Kw+GhQYAIlHxLKdckXYQjMYtYgsPAQLrxUazQm1a5stYkzYGPHnCVXVkk+7JOWfYTlfHciw0BDAZkIvpMMqCLVeeZ6vAGrGGoQEy61Sik3qlfo6pVO2os8IiMCIJDdfqW73zMgskh4O2hp3gjjcokksmesPhiCR6O+-Sxy7U+b52oRuBRu2MYimqkKBQAejr9YbjabzZbrbb7fr1e8ymgADESNF7VAAOTkMDhYdQAA+I8gliQw68CmttqH2cRdxIKH7g85IhdHQARGPwof+vvkke5xYkGeRMSVmSvHWoCvDcA+kUcSxj+P9IeuEPa9bzYLs3ygB9NwABnNddpW3AcfGATlnxrV99UNSDVigvopVVRJ1SeBDBy4DxazQrD4hgnEkHICtowPD0AFsMyQKgCAUSiSCgi9SUPG94hIEAz2kKAX0EqgSAAQigfikEE4SoB8Yg8CoQ06IQHwAHM8DlZkqCgHckJEZcMIg-CAEZzS4niDyAigbxEsS0KoABrcgQHI9CbUwyzcJVJECNRAxf1PJxsVcH9gMPcovK4qyaLotw6gIKAWOANiOPkeLeKvBzbxDZzMBIEhJJk+z50PJSVLU8tNJ0vTgAM0L-xM+RwK4gAmazLNylqICcl83I8ryOvwzr-PCaUUQ1L9IoqxzAJPf9YvkF8uqgRKK3MlY0tY9jTJ8qA4B6wLOvvZMQ1Gsy4E-CKSii-KANk5aBtA7wgA)

Answer (score 1):

One way to make sure an array defined *after* a type has all exactly its keys (no more or less) is to use an object as a "stepping stone" and then apply [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to that object:

```
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'peach';
const fruitObject: {
  [ key in Fruit ]: undefined
} = { apple: undefined, peach: undefined };
const fruitArray = Object.keys(fruitObject);
```

(Seems like there *ought* to be a nicer way of doing this without the need for the intermediary object but I haven't found one).

**UPDATE:** Here is a slightly longer version, which tidies up by setting the intermediary object to `undefined` afterwards since it is unlikely to be needed again.

```
type Fruit = "apple" | "peach";
let tempFruitObject:
  | {
      [key in Fruit]: undefined;
    }
  | undefined = { apple: undefined, peach: undefined };
const fruitArray = Object.keys(tempFruitObject);
tempFruitObject = undefined;
```