# How to find all untranslated strings of a Vuejs project?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, internationalization, translation

I am recently working with a legacy code in **Vue.js** with **Typescript**. The project has the **vue-i18n** library integrated to handle translations and they are managed with `this.$t` in all components of the project, also the translations are contained in directory `translations/[en/es]/FileName.ts` like:

```
//translations/en/Forms.ts

export default {
  Fields: {
    Name: "Name",
    LastName: "Last name",
    Direction: "Full direction",
    ZipCode: "Zip code",
    Phone: {
        Number: "Number",
        Prefix: "Prefix"
    }
  }
};
```

And translation usage is:

```
//pages/UserForm.vue

<div>
   <label> {{$t("Fields.Direction")}} </label>
   <input type="text" name="directionField" required />
</div>
```

However, within the `<templates>` there are many strings that don't use the library because the previous developers included these strings manually like:

```
<div v-if="hasError">
    Oops! There seem to be bugs
</div>
```

*My question*: Is there a method, library, plugin or script that can warn of all strings without translation?

Comment: Where do you get translation strings from? Also you mention, that it is a legacy project. Do you use TypeScript?

Comment: Are translations in `.ts` files or in `.json`?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry. I edited the question to add information.

Comment: Good. Please share example of these `.ts` files. I think your case can be managed with pure typescript

Comment: Done. Its only a Typescript file with key-value pairs or key-object pairs.

Comment: I started working on an answer, please update question with translation usage example

Answer (score 2):

If you use VS Code, there is a really great plugin called "i18n-ally" that has a feature to detect hard-coded strings.

It's an action you can find in the command palette. (At this time is is marked as experimental, but I've had some success with it)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have two options:

1. Runtime check via validation methods
2. Compile time check via typing functions

## Runtime check

This one is pretty straightforward, just run all translations through some helper function, that throws error into the console, if translation is not present. But I think, **vue-i18n** already provides such functionality and you are here for option number 2.

## Compile time check

You can make your translation function typesafe by providing types for incoming values.

### Problem number one

Typing access to deeply nested structures via simple strings can be a really difficult task. If your goal is to type `$t` the way it will not accept any strings other than paths present in your translations. It **can only be done using [new TypeScript 4.1 version](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/)**. To update to latest version, run `npm i -D typescript`.

I already asked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64014465/is-there-a-way-to-declare-a-union-type-in-typescript-with-computed-strings-based) and got pretty far with this one. You can check out [github repo of my `properly-typed` project](https://github.com/temoncher/properly-typed). Types, handy for your task can be found [here](https://github.com/temoncher/properly-typed/blob/master/src/object/object-utils.ts).

It can look something like this:

```
type TranslationsStructure = {
    Fields: {
        Name: string,
        LastName: string,
        Direction: string,
        ZipCode: string,
        Phone: {
            Number: string,
            Prefix: string
        }
    }
}

const typedTranslate = <
  T extends Record<string, unknown>,
  P extends Leaves<T, D>,
  D extends string = '.',
>(path: P): OutputType<T, P, D> => {
  return /* use `$t(path)` here to get translation */path as any;
};

// correct, because `Fields.Name` path exists in `TranslationsStructure`
typedTranslate<TranslationsStructure, 'Fields.Name'>('Fields.Name');

// errors, because `Foo.bar` path exists in `TranslationsStructure`
typedTranslate<TranslationsStructure, 'Foo.bar'>('Foo.bar');
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchAewoF4oG0CwAoKUCMANFAExEDMRALEQKxEBsRA7EQBxECcB2ueADETyF8pfBXzV8dfI3wt87fFx4kB2ALoBubNgRgA9gCckoSFABS+gJYA7ADwBpIgAUiAESgJgEGwBMAzlD+wIa2AOYoUADkAPRRAHyRDp6IPgFBIeFQAD5QNgCuALYARhCGKgD8UM4p3n6BwaE2EbkFJWUquFUABgAkAN4OAL4DUVG1aYE1VWNQAFxQbiP9zkPdnfN5EABuHTibNjtl2li68AbGUKbQAEKGEACGANZ2ACoT9RlNYe4f6Y3hRKod5eSZQPr9WwAMzKUAAYsslgNobCAPprSrwv6BCEowxQdEDJGQmww-Ho9b7LpbXblKmbEGpT4QhFE5Z4qAAJQx9OpaDhRE56g2uAWh1pKgWaFeRDGWh0WD0RhM4GgAHl8sAwJrXqq3kRkqDPgDmr8jf9Ms1IrEEpETRFzYEHJjxXtRV8so7Fhsqq66bh3fbsVAnhAQPooVBXiKoL6jv6A+7DUz0mMY9To7yAws7o8Xk5FokvWgOQKoByhemA1U4cHQ+HI5nE83q1ANVqdXrXvz1EQAKKIQwPADGwDsnKI9vi7niVcTYvjc4O8ZOZwuKrMABlHrt-HYVDKVB4vUHUDbuPsAJKvPucgCCr0vapgwbapXxqDUWCBUeDnIgw5GL4dj2kQ+Q2E8Nj6AA7jYs70lU-ToMktghmGEZRuoAC0FQLJYtiOEQ24PLubxoA4vaLEQcCIGg163g+T4wOo06FlAQxoPWGGvMK9ILGMq5YNcUZDjY-gADYPMAVj6GJADKIT5KO+T3JE-QbHCVgQOJAQLOpWa4DADyFBACygVWm4PMERkmWZlo-FWbhWPco4yTYdnfBeLa4AAWlYYAAML6L4pkeqaVbOAAFrJoX6d5zYwEU74eeEXnxQGzj3FCVjwClzRVkMGyFVgxXYIBYkbhAvivKJElSdAqD7vsjJ1Ok-6AYYwGgVA4GQTBcFpTUXrEaRMqFmlx4pg09nWgAdFEF7xAAFGAUmRQszgAJQLO22rALqkD6tUM4oIkcVQPcwAqTYUAxAAVD1-jQH0wArWtm3dFAkVlNAwD6FAYQQCYtWSdJslQHdMSrcAkVQFZcM2CAJxDIJMQxFAHUucARClMODz5E94KadpASzTZECfdDsMIFYwSBKh3Q1Q8Ymg25-gKYYSlXfclLXNVIP1W8Atg-JinKfcsrEzp-hk8ZEAJEtURS6T5NRJtCpo54hiGEY-g4wB+OE90cL6Pos3FA8hiU2tKS08A9M3YzwtsxzXMqRT2B80zLOC97dUi+zYvcxAkum+blsK0rYcW4YavYEAA)

Maybe I will release it as NPM package soon, when I will have a time to do so. I will keep this thread updated.

### Problem number two

Different languages can have different translations missing. In this case you will need a typecheck, based on a chosen language. So your `typedTranslate` function will need to have different types passed for different translations.

```
const en = {
    Fields: {
        Name: "Name",
        LastName: "Last name",
        Direction: "Full direction",
        ZipCode: "Zip code",
        Phone: {
            Number: "Number",
            Prefix: "Prefix"
        }
    }
};

const typedTranslate = <
  T extends Record<string, unknown>,
  P extends Leaves<T, D>,
  D extends string = '.',
>(path: P): OutputType<T, P, D> => {
  return /* use `$t(path)` here to get translation */path as any;
};

// correct, because `Fields.Name` path exists in `en` object
typedTranslate<typeof en, 'Fields.Name'>('Fields.Name')

// errors, because `Foo.bar` path exists in `en` object
typedTranslate<typeof en, 'Foo.bar'>('Foo.bar')
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchAewoF4oG0CwAoKUCMANFAExEDMRALEQKxEBsRA7EQBxECcB2ueADETyF8pfBXzV8dfI3wt87fFx4kB2ALoBubNgRgA9gCckoSFABS+gJYA7ADwBpIgAUiAESgJgEGwBMAzlD+wIa2AOYoUADkAPRRAHyRDp6IPgFBIeFQAD5QNgCuALYARhCGKgD8UM4p3n6BwaE2EbkFJWUquFUABgAkAN4OAL4DUVG1aYE1VWNQAFxQbiP9zkPdnfN5EABuHTibNjtl2li68AbGUKbQAEKGEACGANZ2ACoT9RlNYe4f6Y3hRKod5eSZQPr9WwAMzKUAAYsslgNobCAPprSrwv6BCEowxQdEDJGQmww-Ho9b7LpbXblKmbEGpT4QhFE5Z4qAAJQx9OpaDhRE56g2uAWh1pKgWaFeRDGWh0WD0RhM4GgAHl8sAwJrXqq3kRkqDPgDmr8jf9Ms1IrEEpETRFzYEHJjxXtRV8so7Fhsqq66bh3fbsVAnhAQPooVBXiKoL6jv6A+7DUz0mMY9To7yAws7o8Xk5FokvWgOQKoByhemA1U4cHQ+HI5nE83q1ANVqdXrXvz1EQAKKIQwPADGwDsnKI9vi7niVcTYvjc4O8ZOZwuKrMABlHrt-HYVDKVB4vUHUDbuPsAJKvPucgCCr0vapgwbapXxqDUWCBUeDnIgw5GL4dj2kQ+Q2E8Nj6AA7jYs70lU-ToMktghmGEZRuoAC0FQLJYtiOEQ24PLubxoA4vaLEQcCIGg163g+T4wOo06FlAQxoPWGGvMK9ILGMq5YIBNjBJ4NiRP0GxwlYEAADYBAsklZrgMAPIUEALAARKp6maReLa4JuDzBDpGlQJpRmiTYakQHpVZuFY9yjlY+g2FpcL5LJslQL4jkAcALk2HZylQAAWlYYAAML6L4ZmaeFYBQIBsXBQZ1QABauWZSlpYmMBFO+Wn5e0hipbluDOPcUJWPAWmVRA1XwJpVZDBsrVYEMgnCaJ1y+K8Q4ibJDzeJE+77IydTpP+gGGMBoFQOBkEwXB+nVMGxGkTKharceKYNJaERngAdFEF7xAAFGAw3pQszgAJQLO22rALqkD6tUM4oIkOVQPcwD5IY4kxAAVAt-jQH0wCXddd3dFA6VlNAwD6FAYQQCYA3+ENAWuVAwMxFdwDpVAxkkzYIAnJ1CoxDESVGE5wBEKUw4PPk4PgtJckBEdplw4TxMIFYwSBKh3Q+HD+jFAAVv52C9f1DyDcNEB2NcGE+LKnPyf4PM2Qk51RFr3OmVEd3U7TZSGEY-hMwBrPs90cL6PoR3FA8hh89dKRC8AIviWLNgS9LstYPLmPYyrauRhr0ROy7buGPrhvO677um9gQA)

#### Problem number three

As I see you have folder structures for each language, so you will need to aggregate it somehow into one object or type to use `typedTranslate` function

Comment: Sorry, I think there has been a misunderstanding. All the keys in the project have a translation.

In the VueJS project there are elements (like a `div`) that have a string as content, but that content is not a `$t` function: it is a natural language phrase like "This is an error".

So, I would like to know if exists any tool (as a crawler or similar) that will detect these strings.

Comment: Hm, so you want some tool that will mark every `Ooops!`?

Comment: Yes. `Ooops` or any string that isn't translated.

Comment: How do yo plan to distinct not translated strings?

Comment: That is my question. I have the problem of having a lot of untranslated strings scattered throughout the code.