# Pick keyof object by array of keys

Tags: typescript

I have a class for make SQL query, e.g.:

```
interface QueryConfig<I extends any[] = any[]> {
    name?: string | undefined;
    text: string;
    values?: I | undefined;
}

interface QueryOptions<R> {
    returnColumns?: Array<keyof R>;
    cacheType?: string;
}

interface QueryOptionsWithMandatoryReturnColumns<R> extends QueryOptions<R> {
    returnColumns: Array<keyof R>
}

class DB {
    query<R>(SQL: QueryConfig, options: QueryOptionsWithMandatoryReturnColumns<R>): Promise<Pick<R, typeof options['returnColumns'][number]> | null>;
    query<R>(SQL: QueryConfig): Promise<R | null>;
    query<R>(SQL: QueryConfig, options?: QueryOptions<R>): Promise<R | null>;
    async query<R>(SQL: QueryConfig, options?: QueryOptions<R>) {
        return {name: 'foo'} as R;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
const db = new DB()

class User {
    name!: number;
    surname!: number;
}

db.query<User>({text: `SELECT name FROM user LIMIT 1`}).then(result => {
    console.log(result?.name, result?.surname)
})
```

I want that, if I give to the function's parameter "returnColumns", e.g.:

```
db.query<User>(
    {text:`SELECT name FROM user LIMIT 1`},
    { returnColumns: ['name']}
);
```

TypeScript checks that the generics `query<User>(..)` is coherent with "returnColumns" `(keyof User)`, in this case, TypeScript shows errors:

```
db.query<User>(
// -----^^^^^^
// ERROR: query return only name of User
   {text:`SELECT name FROM user LIMIT 1`},
   { returnColumns: ['name']}
).then(result => {
   console.log(result?.name, result?.surname)
   // ----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   // ERROR: surname is in User but not in returnColumns
})
```

Is this possible?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=37&ssc=3&pln=32&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFdoE8DCB7EGYAcwB4BJZCAD0hABMBnZOELAbQF1kBeFtrgD5kAbwBQySchBwAthAD8ALmSMwUUMWQAfZOgYQiICPQDcEqZFoq1GkMXNTkANzgAbTI2XJKu-fUNQE3MAXzExUEhYRBQMbAB5AAcwYAJGUgAlYXEnKAgwdCgQfA9ZEC8VAEEoKDgsUgBrCCw8GGQsxykERAALCAAVLETFG3VNUPDI6HgkNEwoLCSUtIB1YDAegFlWejgwPAWM-MLivFLyzOEaOiY5hOTUi6zRC0k8gqKS9DLGKpq6xrNVrtQRiMJiBBuOCMZgAEQAQi8nABHeb1LIACgAyqgADIqOILfCEEgAGmQeAeaQJaKWj0Yaw22wYewOWCOH1O53SWQAlCoAApQPCyYCMCCkAXABANTLksBDCDAynLcrsADk7xOXx%206s47BA3wARtBOMJdIa3G5BJ1JKjsJdsXiadhiURiPzkEKRWKJRkdNJ0Faba9kPaFo6cfi7kSCO7ySr6d5CYsqU9BJ7vaLxZkA5brbaWIwsCAEGG0ZHnTHcHGyRS0xVq3S0pdeUinFItUVRDJ5Cp1TA8Hh1SEi%201C2FwQg0mBkPQjbxpBAAO7IBEY3nhSHQ5gAVXFUHbkl7EAAhCpDbITVBC4wTnIzxfjdAJmJ5wA6cP1ffQQQY0MiFYYBKAABliACiuLgTg-TSA%20yAAGIZPEmx6AeyC4uQmzkLBACMIEhKSAHIN0CB9IMwz9nk9pqOq5Jdly3zlCoGonnqYS8u%20GwQCAGJ5Hebizjw2ShtO5RnBA75uHgxB8RAAlgAo74nvR8lBop753kUD6biEm5vkan4Vj%20UB-gBQGgRBUEwXB8iIchqHoOhmHYXhBFiJx3G8fx6m8CJThiYwElSTJckKUpKnID5glKVpJ66ZuQA)

Comment: TS doesn't have so-called "exhaustive array types", so you'd need to add another generic type parameter to keep track of the actual values used... but then TS doesn't have partial generic type argument inference, so you couldn't write `db.query<User>(...)` directly. You'd have to use a workaround like currying, such as `db.query<User>()(...)`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WGGKvW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yep! thanks! it fully address my question

Comment: Okay I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: thank you very much! I was going crazy over this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I'm changing your `QueryOptions` type to

```
interface QueryOptions<K extends PropertyKey> {
    returnColumns?: Array<K>;
    cacheType?: string;
}
```

since your original version only cares about the keys `keyof R` for the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter anyway. Might as well just use key types `K` instead of dragging around a whole object type we're ignoring most of.

---

TypeScript doesn't have the concept of an "exhaustive" array type, in which it enforces that it contains *every* value of its element type.  You could *try* to represent it as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all allowable [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), but that doesn't scale.  You pretty much need to resort to using generics to *verify* that an array is exhaustive, as described in [Enforce that an array is exhaustive over a union type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55265679/2887218) and [Typescript type guard for requiring all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59680489/2887218), by having the compiler infer the set of values actually used, and checking them against the full set.

But since your `query()` method is *already* generic, then you would want something like `query<R, K extends keyof R>(⋯)` where you call it by specifying `R` and letting the compiler infer `K`, like `query<User>(⋯)`.  But TypeScript does not support this sort of "partial" type argument inference. See [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)).  You have to either specify both `R` and `K` or let the compiler infer them both.  But neither option works for you; you must specify `R` (it can't be inferred from anywhere) and the compiler must infer `K` (otherwise you just have the same problem, you could specify `"name" | "surname"` but not actually use both values in the array).

Right now there are only workarounds for microsoft/TypeScript#26242. The one I usually use is [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), where we split `query<R, K extends keyof R>(⋯): ⋯` into `query<R>(): <K extends keyof R>(⋯): ⋯`.  You call `query` and specify `R`, and get a new function out which will infer `R` for you.

Let me call the curried version `getQuery()` (since it "gets" the `query` method.) Then it looks like:

```
class DB {
    getQuery<R>() {
        return <K extends keyof R>(SQL: QueryConfig, options: QueryOptions<K>):
            Promise<Pick<R, K> | null> => this.query<R>(SQL, options)
    }

    query<R>(SQL: QueryConfig): Promise<R | null>;
    query<R>(SQL: QueryConfig, options?: QueryOptions<keyof R>): Promise<R | null>;
    async query<R>(SQL: QueryConfig, options?: QueryOptions<keyof R>) {
        return { name: 'foo' } as R;
    }
}
```

So `getQuery<R>` returns a function of type `<K extends keyof R>(SQL: QueryConfig, options: QueryOptions<K>) => Promise<Pick<R, K> | null>`.  Now you call that function with `QueryOptions<K>`, the compiler will infer `K`, and you'll just get `Pick<R, K>` out (which is I think the real goal here; you don't want to force someone to write out every key of `R`; instead you just want to make sure the output only reflects the actual keys passed in).

Let's test it:

```
db.getQuery<User>()(
    { text: `SELECT name FROM user LIMIT 1` },
    { cacheType: 'request', returnColumns: ['name'] }
).then(result => {
    // ^? (parameter) result: Pick<User, "name"> | null
    console.log(result?.name, result?.surname) // error!
    // -----------------------------> ~~~~~~~
    // Property 'surname' does not exist on type 'Pick<User, "name">'.
})
```

Looks good. `db.getQuery<User>()` returns a new function, which, when called, recognizes that only `name` was passed in, so the output refers to type `Pick<User, "name">` instead of just `User`.  And therefore `result` doesn't have a `surname` property, and you get an error which hopefully spurs you to either go back and add `"surname"` to `returnColumns` or to stop expecting to see `surname` in the result.

---

Of course this is still a workaround; there's no reason at runtime why you'd want to call `db.getQuery()(⋯)` instead of `db.query(⋯)`, but at least it works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFdoE8DCB7EGYAcwB4BJZCAD0hABMBnZOELAbQF1kBeFtrgD5kAbwBQySchBwAthAD8ALmSMwUUMWQAfZOgYQiICPQDcEqZFoq1GkMXNTkANzgAbTI2XJKu-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-uQb4AIy3hWkIXsgIwIOMUwlEWdQSmohbQlm9wtOgbSMCo7CFlOECFtwYQXGyLK5GcdQrm4zZMhOkgAPTMcgAB6CjIGciRwL08hRFctF0jeyokmSx5QNCABExHSdSmr0pijbtHgbgQGybh4MQNEQHRYAKGyxGYXpImGSuTT5lcrFUD0eBQNOmI2QAtK5bnuR5nlec5wgAH7+QFvlOWxOIlFAZTIIWFnEeW9B4Hp0h4M2ND4s2BBXtMKCFsSpJHmOMlyYIhZsvWIpiLuIZ5Se55OJe153o+z6vu+KDfn+AHQEBIFgcgkF1hRVEgLp+m8NUylpGpGlaTpwn0YZxmZqZc1stFVmlWIQA)