# How to enforce all members of a union will be present in an array of objects? How to reduce the array to an object with all union members as keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
    type PoseType = 'front' | 'side' | 'back';
    type PoseInfo = {
        poseType: PoseType,
        data: number,
        other: string
    }
 
    const exampleArray = [
      {
        poseType: 'front',
        data: 1,
        other: 'a'
      },
      {
        poseType: 'side',
        data: 2,
        other: 'b'
      },
      {
        poseType: 'back',
        data: 3,
        other: 'c'
      },
    ]
      
      
    const requiredObject: {[k in PoseType]: PoseInfo}= {
      front:{// <--
        poseType: 'front', //matches the above property
        data: 1,
        other: 'a'
      },
      side:{
        poseType: 'side',
        data: 2,
        other: 'b'
      },
      back:{
        poseType: 'back',
        data: 3,
        other: 'c'
      },
    }
```

How to enforce that:

1. exampleArray will contain an array with all PoseTypes in poseType
   property
2. requiredObject will contain all PoseTypes with object.poseType matching the property
3. How to use Array.reduce, with proper types to achieve this type safety?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Understood. Thanks for the tip. I probably could have put more details on the ways I have tried and could not get it working. I already knew why my solutions did not work. These problems looked linked to me somehow. I thought this way would explain the problem I was facing more clearly without leading the answers in the ways I was doing it wrong. I am new to this. I will keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oof there's a lot of pieces to your question.  First, to represent what you're doing, I'd suggest defining a type corresponding to "`PoseInfo` with a particular `PoseType` value".  I think we can just make `PoseInfo<T>` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in the particular `PoseType`, and have the generic type parameter [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to the full union so the type `PoseInfo` without a generic type parameter is the same as before:

```
type PoseInfo<T extends PoseType = PoseType> = {
  poseType: T,
  data: number,
  other: string
}
```

---

Question 1: How can we enforce that `exampleArray` will contain an array with all `PoseTypes`?

Answer: TypeScript doesn't have an easy way to refer to an "exhaustive array" like this.  There's no specific type corresponding to that, or at least not one that scales well.  There are a bunch of existing questions in SO about exhaustive arrays in TypeScript, with different approaches... such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265679/enforce-that-an-array-is-exhaustive-over-a-union-type) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58170994/2887218).

The approach I'll use here is to represent the exhaustive array as a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) enforced by a helper function:

```
const exhaustivePoseInfoArray = <T extends PoseType>(
  arr: readonly PoseInfo<PoseType extends T ? T : Exclude<PoseType, T>>[]
) => arr;
```

This examines the passed-in array and figures out union `T` of all of the `poseType` properties of its elements.  If it is the full `PoseType` union, everything is fine.  Otherwise it will figure out which ones are missing (`Exclude<PoseType, T>`) and demands that the array contain that element.

What we will do is pass a candidate array to `exhaustivePoseInfoArray()`, which will just return the input.  If it does so with no compiler warning, then the array has all the required elements.  Otherwise, there will be some sort of warning (whether or not the warning makes sense is debatable):

```
const exampleArray = exhaustivePoseInfoArray([
  {
    poseType: 'front',
    data: 1,
    other: 'a'
  },
  {
    poseType: 'side',
    data: 2,
    other: 'b'
  },
  {
    poseType: 'back',
    data: 3,
    other: 'c'
  },
]); // no error!

const badArray = exhaustivePoseInfoArray([
  { poseType: "front", data: 1, other: "a" }]) // error!
//  ~~~~~~~~ Type '"front"' is not assignable to type '"side" | "back"'. ‍♂️
```

So you can see that `exampleArray` is accepted, while `badArray` is rejected with a warning saying that it's missing `"side"` and `"back"`.

---

Question 2: How can we enforce that `requiredObject` will contain all `PoseType`s with the key matching the `poseType` property?

Here we can luckily at least define a specific [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) that satisfies this requirement:

```
type RequiredObject = { [K in PoseType]: PoseInfo<K> }
```

It just says "for every `K` in the `PoseType` union, a `RequiredObject` has a property with key `K` and value `PoseInfo<K>`.  Let's test it out:

```
const requiredObject: RequiredObject = {
  front: {
    poseType: 'front', 
    data: 1,
    other: 'a'
  },
  side: {
    poseType: 'side',
    data: 2,
    other: 'b'
  },
  back: {
    poseType: 'back',
    data: 3,
    other: 'c'
  },
} // no compiler warning

const badObject: RequiredObject = {
  front: {
    poseType: 'front',
    data: 1,
    other: 'a'
  },
  side: {
    poseType: 'front', // error!
    //~~~~~~ <-- Type '"front"' is not assignable to type '"side"'
    data: 2,
    other: 'b'
  },
  back: {
    poseType: 'back',
    data: 3,
    other: 'c'
  },
}
```

So good, so far.

---

Question 3: How can we use `Array.reduce()`, with proper types to achieve this type safety?

I'm afraid it's not really possible for the compiler to understand inside the implementation of a function that the exhaustive array in the answer to Question 1 can be converted into the required object in the answer to Question 2 via `Array.reduce()`.  This would require the compiler to understand more about the type manipulation of *unspecified* generic type parameters, which it can't do very well.  Instead it will complain that the array might not be a `PoseInfo[]`, or that the accumulator might not be a `RequiredObject`, or that the value read from the array might not be appropriate to add to the accumulator at a key corresponding to its `poseType` property.

Therefore we are going to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that *we* are sure that the types work out.  This shifts the burden of verifying type safety away from the compiler (which can't do it) to us (who need to be careful):

```
const exhaustivePoseInfoArrayToRequiredObject = <T extends PoseType>(
  arr: readonly PoseInfo<PoseType extends T ? T : Exclude<PoseType, T>>[]
) => (arr as any as PoseInfo[]).reduce(
  <T extends PoseType>(acc: RequiredObject, i: RequiredObject[T]) =>
    ((acc[i.poseType] as RequiredObject[T]) = i, acc),
  {} as RequiredObject
);
```

This function claims to turn an exhaustive array into a `RequiredObject`.  Let's see if it does:

```
const req = exhaustivePoseInfoArrayToRequiredObject(exampleArray);
// const req: RequiredObject
console.log(req);
/*  {
  "front": {
    "poseType": "front",
    "data": 1,
    "other": "a"
  },
  "side": {
    "poseType": "side",
    "data": 2,
    "other": "b"
  },
  "back": {
    "poseType": "back",
    "data": 3,
    "other": "c"
  }
}  */
```

Looks good!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwgFXNAvFA5AMwE5wB2wWUAPtggJYAmEpFWARgIYDGA1lgNwBQokWIggBJQjjgAeZFAgAPYBEI0EQpKkGZ46tAD4omAN68oUMMI0QAXFGQAaE1BotgLG4QCuAWyYQ8D0zhgAAs-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-zhL8SE4tF0NlajsLovDSKUv8rVUlNgMjPwCDDfkAzjeNJAAWnshNBCTNTGy3DMsxzPMCyLaBS3LFzK1IxtUK4pltL44U9McRioF-S1dwA+sxRRcKePFLDsAEnkHFPDVl31H4-kPIF3mQOAn2km9xLkmoZHkeppnGSBWnaTooG6XoBiGAFik2K1JgaGZ5hkJYVjWDYWogHZkD2I5TnOKAWkubNVBYQgqhzHdASOE4mynDw2AgNpTFqRqpkaf9WnYNhJOfGrZOAHYqHu6rbzfYB9mQX10F0fkWhWtg2H2KgmxYvc1qgKrrw++9vt+rcdluk5iXiKGYZkz7TnVETLz1DIDV+I0+okU0Ksxx7PpaB4nheU01QjQMCs6sc3th2rgDPO44BeJt+jgGIWkvRm-QAKlMElkwdG1DNtCHqxsaXiCdfkbXpWWtLV91NZtL1BNMYK6E1hKbQV3Wq1V8V1clTXKOtnWlaYG0DdtesTbV82nfYq3IRt1xNYyv3HdtNgXZ5BJTDFv0gA)

Or [this link](https://tsplay.dev/DmM5bm) if you need no repeats as well as none missing

Comment: It was probably not worded well in the question, but the exhaustivePoseInfoArray allows multiple poseType objects with same value in the array. Is there some length check or something better that I can add to the conditional?

Comment: It just gets more complicated but it is doable, possibly like [this](https://tsplay.dev/DmM5bm), where you force a tuple type and make sure that there are no repeat elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have a type `PoseInfo`, so you can declare your `exampleArray` as an array of `PoseInfo` objects.

```ts
type PoseType = 'front' | 'side' | 'back';

type PoseInfo = {
        poseType: PoseType,
        data: number,
        other: string
    }

const exampleArray: PoseInfo[];
```

Comment: I think they want to ensure that the key matches the value of `poseType`