# Exhaustive keyof type

Tags: typescript

I'm working in a typescript application that retrieve data from an api (actually OData api).

The api allow to specify which fields to retrieve. Like `api/some/getbyid(42)?$select=x,y,z` to get `x`, `y` and `z` fields, along some technical fields that are always retrieved (like `id` or `author`)

I have model types that reflect the api output :

```js
type APIItem = {
  id : number; 
  author : string; 
}

type CustomerModel = APIItem  & {
  firstName : string;
  lastName:string;
  age : number
}
```

I wrap the retrieval logic into an function that ask the ID and the fields to retrieve, call the API and *cast* the result:

```js
const fakeApi = (id: number, fields : string[]): Promise<APIItem> => {
  // build api URL, fetch, ....
  const result = JSON.parse(`{
    "id": ${id}, "firstName": "Mark", "lastName": "Hamill", "age": 20, "author": "d@some.com"
  }`) ;
  return Promise.resolve(result);
}

const loadFromDB = async <
TModel extends APIItem
>(
  id: number, // Item ID in the api
  fields : (keyof Omit<TModel, 'id'> & string)[] // Fields to retrieve. Omit Id because it will be always included
  ): Promise<TModel> => {

  const fromDb = await fakeApi(id, fields);
  const result = fromDb as TModel;
  return Promise.resolve(result);
}

const customerPromise = loadFromDB<CustomerModel>(42, ['firstName']); // Coding error : missing fields
customerPromise.then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

This is working as expected except for one point: the consumer code has to specify all fields to retrieve. In the above example, only the `firstName` fields is retrieved, resulting in a incomplete object.

Is there any (simple) way to ensure all fields from the model are provided in the API call ?

As far as I know, there's no way in TS to iterate keys in type, because types are not part of the actual JS output.

What I'd like is to ensure the calling code specify ALL fields (or the function be able to guess itself the fields):

```
loadFromDB<CustomerModel>(42, ['firstName', 'lastName', 'age']);
```

This way, the models will always be complete.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?pretty=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAggCgSQcCBbKBeKBvAUFKASwBMoAuKAOwFdUAjCAJwG4p8oBDa4ACwHtG5KAGdgjQpQDmrXAF9cuUJCgBhaqL6omAWT7EIAG0yxEyNAQBkOdgDNCjUQDkOWoaPFTm7AxycuIZO4S0uwcktAUNPRMcgoAxnyUolA2HADWEDBghMYAFCSRtAyMADQphIbEwm5iwQDaALoAlEJwjJqEwhAAPCZIKKgAfJiDeAQA9ONQdNSEBqQc2VAAqgBKADJlNhDAcTxlAHRHB+wJScBQjBDC1AYXWABSAMoA8o4HYBwOELkABtYEAgAIhIQKEABJsCRZGUgXYHMBnFogRQgdovmkgbCfH5kUIgQAJFxzAxYqBAsIQFFQABMAAZYVxeAIwajiAABYSaCAHBKoIHsWS-FpeAhXYDURiUKBtDpdA5XLkGABuP0Vt2ATS88lwZ2SBj4HGIADF2qgACIAIWMvhAlDiUG6uAAKrp9EYIAAPFCUKp9MyoXCDXLsApUIpMMqTKABmPmojS3jQRaEWwVebVCi5DIgPg2KAvVCEYDdV16QxlADkJErwysQSkTUaUGjxvTfuAfEuO3EEFVBwLRYuCFIDDiXC6RAuAHcSdNkwZpxwQNUJHEDNR9MR2C0KLKi11S27DMMMKMFAQ9RcbGbzXQbUviyl0plsvliFt28ItReoFfuzcdzGDemh3pw1Rlu6XjsOKkrSvunQ8oqfAqmq1waj+Or-nE6idlojAIZOWAGkapqgZa3RqBo+HHgYwYACw0mUdSVvCuIQJWzReDh1FMIRPJJpQuR6ihPIGpITS8hwuw8MJiRKjyTDtIwWpAA)

Comment: Your example has missing types, plase provite a working example as a link to https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: @Dimava **And** an (optional) link, not just *as* a link. :-) The full MRE must be here, on-site.

Comment: What's missing ? the whole code in my repro is here. Anyways I link the playground code

Comment: @SteveB - Indeed, I don't see anything missing either. :-)

Comment: See my edit. I tried to be clearer

Comment: Sounds like you should be using classes and not types?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer: not sure to see how class can help. It may allow to add some runtime check, but not sure it will add coding type checking. But maybe I miss some point ?

Comment: Ahh - so you want both Run-time and Compile-time checks. Yeah, classes wouldn't help with compile-time checks.

Comment: V. minor side-note: You mentioned casting. TypeScript doesn't have casting, it has *type assertions*, which are similar but also quite different. In languages that have casting, a cast can actually change the runtime value (for instance, in Java casting a `double` to an `int` changes the value from an IEEE-754 double-precision floating point bit pattern to a two's complement bit pattern for the trunc'd integer value). TS's type assertions have **no** runtime effect at all, they're purely you, the programmer, asserting to TypeScript that you know that the thing in question is of the given type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In situations where I want both runtime information and compile-time information, I try to set things up so I can derive the compile-time information from the data I use for the runtime information, since in most cases I can't go the other way (enums being a special case). In particular, "exhaustive arrays" like you describe are problematic, see [jcalz's answer about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66271167/157247).

To do that here, you might define `CustomerModel` in terms of a `CustomerModelFields` object that has the field names and unused representative values:

```typescript
// Primary source of truth is an object with the names of the fields and representative unused values
const CustomerModelFields = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    age: 0,
};

// Model is derived from the fields object
type CustomerModel = APIItem & typeof CustomerModelFields;
```

(I haven't included `author` there because it wasn't in the fields array of your sample call that should work and because, like `id`, it's part of `APIItem`. But your code only explicitly excludes `id`, so add it if it should be there.)

Then `loadFromDB` accepts that fields object type as its type parameter and uses it for the `fields` (now it's an object rather than an array of strings), and derives its return type from the fields object:

```typescript
const loadFromDB = async <Fields extends object>(
    id: number, // Item ID in the api
    fields: Fields // Fields to retrieve. Omit Id because it will be always included
): Promise<APIItem & Fields> => {
    const fromDb = await fakeApi(id, Object.keys(fields));
    const result = fromDb as APIItem & Fields;
    return Promise.resolve(result);
};
```

When calling it, you only *have* to say one thing (the fields), not two (the type and fields):

```typescript
const customer = await loadFromDB(42, CustomerModelFields);
```

...although in that example, the type of `customer` would be shown as `APIItem & { firstName: string; lastName: string; age: number; }`. That's the same as `CustomerModel`, but doesn't have that alias associated with it. If you wanted that specific alias, you could specify the type on the constant:

```typescript
const customer: CustomerModel = await loadFromDB(42, CustomerModelFields);
```

Full example ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&pretty=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAggCgSQcCBbKBeKBvAUFAqASwBMAuKAOwFdUAjCAJwG59CBDa4ACwHtGKAZ2CMilAOasAvq1wB6OVDijU7RiCiDe1RgGNovAGZQRXbsUFR2lKLzoArCLuBQA7kR4nu0Su1QRLIy9oQyIIABsSS2sSKEYIMHjBCEpgdmAiADdoahpk2Mz2cOoA3F1eSmEoAGFqYV5-RgBZXhIIgDEwyMssPEIoUMZhADk-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-RGi4Y7mgMPF8YsgJ8iC4LgW2hAdl2tEcskA4BEOI7qROU4EluO5QASzLCu6-QiBoor9AQqlQLoXw-Iw-HsIJc4LkuDTrgSAAs+YUjC3xwq0HQPIIyk+b5M5Dv2c7iASAWwkwGWZeKmWEAAegA-GsUj+ekWrOUwNwCFYlAgK53k+UaOU6s1-BGQQUhrOKNrBe4ng-gRRCLGsnnueVfmFUlTAUIlQXwiFYXzouPFrrF8WfEVzQpQiaUld12XhLlvD5ctQUXf0ZXlVA1W1fVmrmAS-WtdYHULZlPXXX1jAtYNUDDVIzIuawQA)):

```typescript
type APIItem = {
    id: number;
    author: string;
};

// Primary source of truth is an object with the names of the fields and representative unused values
const CustomerModelFields = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    age: 0,
};

// Model is derived from the fields object
type CustomerModel = APIItem & typeof CustomerModelFields;

const fakeApi = (id: number, fields: string[]): Promise<APIItem> => {
    // build api URL, fetch, ....
    const result = JSON.parse(` {
    "id" : ${id}, "firstName": "Mark", "lastName" : "Hamill", "age": 20, "author" : "d@some.com"
  }`);
    return Promise.resolve(result);
};

const loadFromDB = async <Fields extends object>(
    id: number, // Item ID in the api
    fields: Fields // Fields to retrieve. Omit Id because it will be always included
): Promise<APIItem & Fields> => {
    const fromDb = await fakeApi(id, Object.keys(fields));
    const result = fromDb as APIItem & Fields;
    return Promise.resolve(result);
};

(async () => {
    try {
        const customer = await loadFromDB(42, CustomerModelFields);
        console.log(customer);
        //          ^? const customer: APIItem & { firstName: string; lastName: string; age: number }
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error;
    }
    // Or with the alias
    try {
        const customer: CustomerModel = await loadFromDB(42, CustomerModelFields);
        console.log(customer);
        //          ^? const customer: CustomerModel
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error;
    }
})();
```

Comment: @DaneBrouwer - I couldn't tell for sure, but given the OP's example call that should work left `"author"` out of the array, I decided to leave it out. Easy enough for the OP to add it if it's meant to be there, but...